# Jquery popup add

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add the wp enqueue scripts and make the 'magnific popup' work here: http://innovation.partsmaster.com/

I've made jQuery work on the site through the 'custom-jquery.js' file with this in the functions.php file:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script('custom-jquery', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/custom-jquery.js', array('jquery'), '20131022' );
```

but then I don't understand how to add a plugin like the magnific popup. I was just wanting to use the script and do a simple jquery function in the header.php file. I can't figure out why adding this doesn't work:

```
function magnific_popup_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jqueryui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryui' );
wp_register_script( 'magnificpopup', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/_scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'magnificpopup' );
wp_register_style('magnificcss',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/magnific-popup.css');
wp_enqueue_style('magnificcss');
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'magnific_popup_scripts');
```

Please help me figure out how. I was trying to set it up in the functions.php file but then I started to get desperate because nothing seemed to work and was attacking it in the header.php. Any ideas?

My console says this:
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://innovation.partsmaster.com/css/magnific-popup.css
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.3/jquery.min.js
- Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.min.js:5
- Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.magnific-popup.js:38
- Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined innovation.partsmaster.com/:23
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=2.1.05:10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double check your code in `functions.php` again, because it looks like you're trying to load this invalid URL:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.3/jquery.min.js
```

And you're probably wanting to load this one:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

[edit]

You might also make sure that broken reference isn't being added in your `header.php` either.  Upon closer inspection, it looks like you might have those references hard coded there too.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I was able to rework everything. It was my jquery 1.10.3 reference, it was supposed to be 1.10.2 actually once I looked back at the jquery ui. I still don't know that I understand everything but it seems to be working. I'm still just barely understanding what's going on. It looks like I'll need to review what I did a few times.